# Overloading symbolic toolbox functions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In Matlab we can overload any function. The convention is to place the new/overloaded function file inside a folder which addresses the data type prepended by an '@'-sign. A famous example can be found [here](http://slo.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/symbolic/ch15.html).

```
function z = sinc(x)
%SINC The symbolic sinc function
%     sin(x)/x. This function
%     accepts a sym as the input argument.
if isequal(x,sym(0))
   z = 1;
else
   z = sin(x)/x;
end
```

Placing the sinc.m in Windows e.g. under \anywhereOnPath\@sym\ will work under Matlab2009b. However it will not work in Matlab2011b. This issue is specific to the 'sym' data type (e.g. double works just fine for me). Is there a new setting that I missed?

## Update1

```
>> syms u
>> pretty(sinc(u))
```

Matlab 2009b will return:

```
ans =
       sin(u)
       ------
         u
```

Matlab 2011b will return:

```
Undefined function 'sinc' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
```

## Update2

The suggestions being made by user WalkingRandomly on his page [Explorations in overriding MATLAB functions](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4776) wont work, too. Placing the file in the symbolic toolbox root folder (\MATLAB[VersionOfMatlab]\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym) and updating with `rehash TOOLBOXRESET` also wont't help.

## Update3

W.r.t horchlers comment:
`set MATLAB_SYMBOLIC=matlab` is used in R2009b since maple does not work here.
For the test I once deleted all unwanted files temporarily. Below you will find the complete test with omitted results where sinc.m was loaded from signal toolbox. Since I have no access to R2011b right now I just did the test with R2013b again which causes the same result. Between 2009 and above versions many things beyond UI were changed. so obviously its purpose and no bug (therefore I will keep R2009b to be able to run my legacy code ;).

```
>>
>> %using 32bit R2009b on Windows XP 32bit
>> rehash TOOLBOXRESET
>> which -all sinc %signal file removed
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\sinc.m  % sym method
>> pretty(sinc(u))

  sin(u) 
  ------ 
    u
>> 
>> rehash TOOLBOXRESET
>> which -all sinc %signal file recovered
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\toolbox\signal\signal\sinc.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\sinc.m  % sym method
>> pretty(sinc(u)) %takes signal file since higher in path

  sin(u) 
  ------ 
    u
>> 
>> %using 32bit R2013b on Windows 7 64bit
>> rehash TOOLBOXRESET
>> which -all sinc %signal file removed
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\sinc.m  % sym method
>> pretty(sinc(u))
Undefined function 'sinc' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
>> 
>> rehash TOOLBOXRESET
>> which -all sinc %signal file recovered
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\signal\signal\sinc.m
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\@sym\sinc.m  % sym method
>> pretty(sinc(u)) %takes signal file since higher in path

  +-           -+ 
  |  sin(pi u)  | 
  |  ---------  | 
  |    pi u     | 
  +-           -+
>>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Are you sure the 2009b version is actually calling your function and not some other one? Run `which sinc` in the command window. I assume that you've tried the other `rehash` options (e.g., `toolboxcache`) with no success too?

Comment: No I did not figure it out yet. But I stopped my research after making Update2. Please see Update3.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to overload anything? How about just changing to a new function name? (`mysinc`)

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin its simply a matter of taste. I don't have to. Its actually connected to learning different languages and applying (general) concepts and techniques.

Comment: I don't say it is bad to practice and learn, but it may be worth noting that I personally experienced the general attitude amongst matlab programmers to be: 'Don't overload unless you have good reason to'.